# Adding callback parameter to $.ajax with jsonp

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I am trying to implement jQuery ajax call for cross domain call using jsonp, and the code is like -

```
$.ajax({
    async:true,
    cached:true,
    url: 'cfcs/TempRepository.cfc?method=getAllCategories'
        +'&storeID='+ storeId
        +'&callback=?',
    type: 'get',
    data: '',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: PopulateCategoryObject,
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr + ',' + status + ',' + error);
    }
});

function PopulateCategoryObject(results) {
    //populate the categories
}
```

I am confused here with the use of callback. 
If I remove success attribute of $.ajax and use callback=PopulateCategoryObject in place of callback=? like -

```
$.ajax({
    async:true,
    cached:true,
    url: 'cfcs/TempRepository.cfc?method=getAllCategories'
        +'&storeID='+ storeId
        +'&callback=PopulateCategoryObject',
    type: 'get',
    data: '',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr + ',' + status + ',' + error);
    }
});
```

the difference it makes is, it returns result like -

```
PopulateCategoryObject, jQuery172012112959187034678_1376976441013( // data here )
```

And, the function PopulateCategoryObject is not executed.

I am unable to figure it out how to set the callback function here? and why is "jQuery172012112959187034678_1376976441013" getting added here with the result?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Why do you need to remove success property ???

Comment: I want to call "PopulateCategoryObject" directly, rather than through success, because each time "jQuery172012112959187034678_1376976441013" is added to the url and the ajax call is not getting cached here.

Keeping callback=PopulateCategoryObject, may keep it cached. I am not sure  about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.ajax({
    cached:true,
    url: 'cfcs/TempRepository.cfc?method=getAllCategories' + '&storeID=' + storeId,
    jsonpCallback: 'PopulateCategoryObject',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr + ',' + status + ',' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Arun, it's returning PopulateCategoryObject(//result), but the function is not getting called, is there anything else we need to set?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your ajax call to cache: set the `"cache"` parameter to `false`...
otherwise set it to `true`.

Another thing...if you don't want to use `"success"` parameter to trigger your callback, try jquery `$.deffer`:
Read this! : http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/